# Subtracting each element of list from every elements on its right in the same list

Tags: python, list

I need to manipulate list to get subtraction (subtracting each number from every number on its right).

I have tried using below code which is working with 2 for loops, is there anyway I can do it in only 1 for loop or in a better way then I did.

```
list=[3,2,5,4,3]
output_list = [0]

    for element in list:
        for i in range(0, length(list)):
            new_element = [ (list[i] - element) if i > index(element) else 0]
            if new_element > 0:
                output_list.append( new_element )
```

example:
input `[3,2,5,4,3]`

subtract like `[2-3, 5-3, 4-3, 3-3, 5-2, 4-2, 3-2, 4-5, 3-5, 3-4] = [-1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2, 1]`

output with values > 0, first 0 is from initialization `[0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]`

Comment: note that `list` shadows built-in `list` - avoid it!

Comment: @Yash, your last element in expected output is `3-4= -1`. so, it won't come in your expected output.

Comment: Thank you guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should generate the correct output:

```py
values = [3,2,5,4,3]
print([j-i for k,i in enumerate(values[:-1]) for j in values[k+1:] if j-i > 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from operator import sub
>>> l = [3,2,5,4,3]
>>> [0]+[sub(c[1],c[0]) for c in combinations(l,2) if sub(c[1],c[0]) > 0]
[0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension

```
a=[3,2,5,4,3]
b= [j-a[i] for i,v in enumerate(a) for j in a[i+1:] if j-a[i]>0]

print(b)
```

output

```
 [2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```